# jQuery "Like" with id in HTML as identifier

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project, where it's possible for users to like each others stuff. Right now my jQuery gets the id from the HTML, to identify what thing to like. But people are able to open an Inspector in the browser, and edit the id, and that way like a whole other thing.

I am searching for alternative ways to do this.

I've thought of making a unique string, but that's kinda the same, since they still would be able to copy/paste the string to another element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using javascript there is really not much you can do when it comes to security related issues. You have to handle this backend.

Comment: You don't need to worry about evil users manipulating the DOM if you sanitize inputs on the server and do all the permission checking there.

Comment: It's a main problem of webdevelopment, that the users can edit your stuff and it is hard to protect it. The only way I see here, is to generate onetime identifier which are generated in user-context and the context of the thing to like

Comment: @MichaelWalter Could you please detail this a bit?

Comment: you can use sessions to store uniqueID and map them against your ID, so when the requests come to server with edited ID, check the mapping, if its wrong then throw a message.

Comment: @Kolind sorry, it is too much, to  explain it here

Comment: @ntechi So, let's say that this thing to like is a post, you wan't me to store all postId's in a session?

Comment: @ntechi has a good point here. my solution won't worth it, cause it is too much stuff for this little protection. I won't do it.

Comment: on a page you will render around 10-20 posts, when the page loads, save all 20 uniqueIDs in session `$_SESSION[uniqid()] = $id;` when some one likes this check the session mapping, if the page is refreshed then empty your session variable

Comment: @ntechi I can't figure out how this should be coded. No matter what I am trying it's the same, people can change the HTML and like other content. How should I "check" the session mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

//Consider this as your IDs of post which is fetched from database.
$pageIDs = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach($pageIDs as $index => $key)
{
    $uniqueID = uniqid();
    echo '<a href="#" class="like" rel="'.$index.'#'.$uniqueID.'"></a>';
    $_SESSION[$uniqueID] = $index;
}

//Now when someone clicks on like button, pass the rel attribute in as POST variable to PP

if($_POST['id'])
{
    $array = explode('#',$_POST['id']);
    $actualID = $_SESSION[$array[1]];
    if($actualID === $array['0'])
    {
        //Everything is fine
        return true;
    }else{
        //some one edited your HTML code
    }
    //you can destroy your session variable here.
}

?>
```